# Get on gtag.js same features as analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For a new site I am reading the differences between Analytics.js and Gtag.js and I don't seem to find a description for some functionality that I found really useful with Analytics.js as for example

- The total time a user spends on your site.
- The time a user spends on each page and in what order those pages were visited.
- What internal links were clicked (based on the URL of the next pageview).

There were also other minor functionality like:

- The geographic location of the user.
- What browser and operating system are being used.
- The referring site.

These are clearly explained in the Analytics.js documentation, whereas I cannot find any explicit mention of these in the Gtag.js documentation.

Are these automatically available with the standard Gtag.js code I find in my Google Analytics Dashboard, or do I have to configure some specific setting (which I don't seem to find anywhere)?

Answer (score 1):

analytics.js to gtag.js is a library change. What you see in the GA Web UI is not changing. Everything you've mentioned is default EXCEPT for the internal links, you'll need to come up with a solution for that. I don't recall analytics.js did it automatically.